# Spring data jpql (Hibernate) query not working in MySQL database Error: 1241

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have implemented a filter using a jpql Query in spring data JPA.

I am using this class as a filter;

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class FilterTO {
    private Double priceMin;
    private Double priceMax;
    private List<Long> categories;
    private List<String> brands;

    public FilterTO(Double priceMin, Double priceMax, List<Long> categories, List<String> brands) {
        this.priceMin = (priceMin == null)? 0 : priceMin;
        this.priceMax = (priceMax == null)? Double.MAX_VALUE: priceMax;
        this.brands = (brands == null || brands.isEmpty())? null : brands;
        this.categories = (categories == null || categories.isEmpty())? null : categories;
    }
}
```

And this is the method and the query that I am using;

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE " +
            "p.price * (1 - p.discount) BETWEEN :#{#filter.getPriceMin()} AND :#{#filter.getPriceMax()} " +
            "AND ( p.brand IN :#{#filter.getBrands()} OR :#{#filter.getBrands()} IS NULL) " +
            "AND ( p.category.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.id FROM Category c " +
            "WHERE c.parent.id IN :#{#filter.getCategories()}) OR p.category.id IN :#{#filter.getCategories()} OR :#{#filter.getCategories()} IS NULL) ")
    Page<Product> findByFilter(@Param("filter") FilterTO filter, Pageable pageable);
```

This is the query in a clean version:

```
SELECT p FROM Product p WHERE p.price * (1 - p.discount) BETWEEN :#{#filter.getPriceMin()} AND :#{#filter.getPriceMax()} 
AND ( p.brand IN :#{#filter.getBrands()} OR :#{#filter.getBrands()} IS NULL) 
AND ( p.category.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT c.id FROM Category c WHERE c.parent.id IN :#{#filter.getCategories()}) OR p.category.id IN :#{#filter.getCategories()} OR :#{#filter.getCategories()} IS NULL)
```

So basically i filter on the price, categories and brands. If the list of categories is empty, i ignore it and if the list of brands is empty, i ignore it too.

This same query works fine in H2, but when we tried to move to production on MySQL, it's giving this error: **java.sql.SQLException: Operand should contain 1 column(s)**

Comment: I think you should put a paranthesis here **WHERE `(` p.price * (1 - p.discount) BETWEEN :#{#filter.getPriceMin()} AND :#{#filter.getPriceMax()} `)`**

Comment: @raviiii1 thanks for the comment, i have tried that but still getting the same error

Comment: If you change the hibernate logging level you can see the query that he actually sends to the database. In my case that has some brackets where none belong and then I get that mistake. Haven't found the fix yet.